# How do I connect to my existing Git repository using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I've been using Visual Studio code for a long time, since v0.9.1. I now have run into the need to use GitHub and an online Git repository.

I have the online Git repository set up and have been pushing changing to the online repository using GitHub. I have recently come to realize I can save myself a step with using Visual Studio Code to do both: to edit my code, then send it up to the online repository.

I am very new to the whole Git concept. Visual Studio Code had me install the "Git" plugin which installed Git Bash, Git CMD, and Git GUI.

This is the online repository URL I'm trying to get to: https://github.com/SpectrumGraphics/Spectrum-Graphic-Designs.git

[image: Visual Studio Code Git][image: Plugin Visual Studio had my install]

Answer (score 87, accepted):

1. Open Visual Studio Code *terminal* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>)
2. Write the Git clone command. For example,

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
   ```
3. Open the folder you have just cloned (menu *File* → *Open Folder*)

   [image]

Comment: In other words, Visual Studio Code allows you do this OOTB.  Thanks this works and should be a native IDE answer for the OP.

Comment: For newbe to get the URL in (as above)

"Write git clone command. For example
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git"

.. from the GitHub repository: Press [Clone or Download] then the copy icon.

Comment: how do i switch to child branch in VS Code ?

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya - there is no child branch concept in git. it just have a particular commit path. you just witch from branch to branch using git checkout <brachname> command.

Answer (score 23):

Another option is to use the built-in Command Palette, which will walk you right through cloning a Git repository to a new directory.

From [Using Version Control in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_cloning-a-repository):

> You can clone a Git repository with the Git: Clone command in the Command Palette (Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>). You will be asked for the URL of the remote repository and the parent directory under which to put the local repository.

At the bottom of Visual Studio Code you'll get status updates to the cloning. Once that's complete an information message will display near the top, allowing you to open the folder that was created.

Note that Visual Studio Code uses your machine's [Git installation](https://git-scm.com/downloads), and requires 2.0.0 or higher.

Comment: Do you know if Git Cmd https://git-scm.com/download/win  (**caution auto download, but not execute on link**) is required for VS Code clone? I had previously used GItHub Desktop for a clone and it needed the Git Cmd to work.  So it was in place when I did another clone with VS Code.

Comment: Good question. Normally I just install Git, so I had to check. According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-support "Note: VS Code will leverage your machine's Git installation, so you need to install Git first before you get these features. Make sure you install at least version 2.0.0." So yes. Although I'm surprised GitHub Desktop required a separate Git install; I thought it came with one.

Answer (score 8):

1. Use `git clone` to clone your repository into a folder (say *work*). You should see a new subfolder, `work/.git`.
2. Open folder *work* in Visual Studio Code - everything should work fine!

PS: Blow away the temporary folder.

Answer (score 5):

Use the Git GUI in the Git plugin.

**Clone your online repository** with the URL which you have.

After cloning, make changes to the files. When you make changes, you can see the number changes. **Commit** those changes.

**Fetch** from the *remote* (to check if anything is updated while you are working).

If the *fetch* operation gives you an update about the changes in the remote repository, **make a pull** operation which will update your copy in Visual Studio Code. Otherwise, do not **make a pull** operation if there aren't any changes in the remote repository.

Push your changes to the upstream remote repository by making a **push operation**.

Comment: awesome thank you, quick question, its asking me for a source location and target directory?

Comment: When you are trying to clone?

Comment: I think it is the source repository not the source location, which is your url. The target directory or location is your local drive into which you want to clone the remote code.

Comment: Which git GIT Plugin? There's dozens of them.

Comment: You should probably mention which Git plugin you are referring to.

Comment: Re *"Use the Git GUI in the Git plugin"*: How exactly? Can you expand your answer? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33269344/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar), not here in comments.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open  Vs Code
2. Go to view
3. Click on terminal to open a terminal in VS Code
4. Copy the link for your existing repository from your GitHub page.
5. Type “git clone” and paste the link in addition i.e “git clone [https://github.com/...”](https://github.com/...%E2%80%9D)
6. This will open the repository in your Vs Code Editor.