# Visual Studio and remote git server connection

Tags: git, visual-studio, connection, remote-server

I am new to use git on Visual studio and connect it to my git on remote server. I am using visual studio 2015 and its source control git. I comfigure remote access in visual studio. Then I put my id_rsa.pub info the /.ssh/authorized_keys. Click remote setting and add remote git address as git@sthsthsth:myproject.git When I click fetch or publish it returns error 
"Unsupported URL protocol"
&&
failed to fetch remote repository

My question: Does Visual studio git support remote server connection?
[remote setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ827.png)[failed to fetch][2][unsopperted URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y1iB.png)

Comment: Of course it supports remote connection

Comment: @GôTô how is it working? git@secureblalba:myrepo.git not working. It is working with github but not git server in another machine. At least i cannot do it, Can you explain it in detail? i followed Misrosoft tutorial but it did not work

Comment: Maybe these will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263491/how-do-i-connect-to-my-existing-git-repo-using-visual-studio-code and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/02/06/create-connect-and-publish-using-visual-studio-with-git/

Comment: @GôTô I read these pages. they all shows "https://github"  staff. No one shows ssh@ or git@. Did u connect with anyone of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 does not support remote operations over the SSH protocol.