# How to list local branches in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In VSCode terminal I can type `git branch` to display all local branches and this is working fine.

But when I click on 'master' icon in the left bottom corner, it takes me to command `go checkout` and says 'No other branches' Why is that ?

Comment: `go checkout` or `git checkout`?

Comment: Git checkout, sorry

Comment: I found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40179164/4615576. I have to explicitly File->Open Folder where I keep my repo... Before I learned that , I kept opening top directory with all my repos subfolders and was exploring repos hoping that stepping down to specific repo folder in VSCode is actually taking me to that folder